# Array objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

How can I access this array with objects? I'm familiar with the ordinary arrays in Javascript, but this tricks me.

```
var studentsInfo = {};
studentsInfo.students = [];
studentsInfo.students.push({studentId : 100, name: "Peter Hansen", grades : [{grade: "10"},{grade: "12"},{}]});
studentsInfo.students.push({studentId : 101, name: "Jan Olsen", grades : [{grade: "7"},{grade: "10"},{}]});
```

But how to access this and print out the grade for each?
I'm supposed to do an average number for their grades and output this in a table in angular. But now I just want to get the grade out and understand how to access this type. I've tried something like this:

```
 studentInfo.students.grade
```

Comment: `studentInfo.students` is an array. So `studentInfo.students[0]....`.

Comment: So for do you loop through an array and access an index? How to you access a property in an object? Combine them.

Answer (score 1):

It is `class.array.class...`
If you create object with `[]` it is array, with `{}` it is class.

```
alert(studentsInfo.students[0].grades[0]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5qnq8gk8/1/

Answer (score 0):

To access the array:

```
var array = studentsInfo.students;
```

To access the individual elements:

```
var first = studentsInfo.students[0];
var second = studentsInfo.students[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

as `studentInfo.students` is a array you need to get the index of the value to access it.

get grade 1:

```
studentInfo.students[0].grades[0]
```

get grade 2:

```
studentInfo.students[0].grades[1]
```

this will access grades of the first item in the array. As `grades` is another array to step into that again you need to define the index.